# Do I need to pay state tax if I lived in a state for less than a week?

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, income-tax-refund, moving

I lived and worked in Washington state for the most of 2014. At the very end I moved to California on the 28th of December, so technically I lived three days in the state of California (being unemployed at that time). In Washington I do not need to pay a state tax, but do I need to pay state tax for these 3 days in California?

Comment: did you have any income in these three days?

Comment: @littleadv no, no income. I was unemployed and started my job approximately on 10th of January 2015

Comment: Were you a resident of California in 2013?

Comment: no income - no return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you only pay tax on money you earned while in the state in question. Even then generally there are exclusions if you made only a small amount. (Generally earning less than $400 or $500, depending on the state, relieves you a having to file or pay taxes in a state.)

Don't want to pay any state income tax? There are seven states with no state income tax. They are Alaska, Florida, Nevada, South Dakota, Texas, Washington and Wyoming.

Yes, I am a CPA.